# Сортировка массива на андроид

Tags: java, массивы, android

Всем добрый день! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с сортировкой на андроид!
 Есть следующий массив:

```
 [ 13, Иван, yandex.ru, 356 ]
 [ 22, Яков, rambler.ru, 412 ]
 [ 4, Федор, mail.ru, 214 ]
 [ 43, Сергей, google.ru, 323 ]
 [ 17, Владимир, androidforums.ru, 108 ]
 [ 124, Николай, developer.android.com, 219 ]
 [ 9, Леонид, gasgoo.com, 588 ]
```

Нужно отсортировать его по первому элементу, т.е. должно получиться следующее:

```
[ 4, Федор, mail.ru, 214 ]
 [ 9, Леонид, gasgoo.com, 588 ]
 [ 13, Иван, yandex.ru, 356 ]
 [ 17, Владимир, androidforums.ru, 108 ]
 [ 22, Яков, rambler.ru, 412 ]
 [ 43, Сергей, google.ru, 323 ]
 [ 124, Николай, developer.android.com, 219 ]
```

Помогите реализовать. Я знаю что нужно использовать Comparable и могу реализовать его на java, но не знаю как это сделать на андроид.
 Ниже код реализации на java. ПОМОГИТЕ, проект горит а у меня ничего не выходит!
    введите код здесь

```
package com.melikovivan.sort;
    import java.util.*;
    public class Student implements Comparable
    {
      public int student_id;
      public String name;
      public String url;
      public int res;

      public Student(int student_id, String name, String url, int res)
      {
        this.student_id = student_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url; 
        this.res = res;
      }

      /* Перегрузка метода compareTo */

      public int compareTo(Object obj)
      {
        Student tmp = (Student)obj;
        if(this.student_id < tmp.student_id)
        {
              /* текущее меньше полученного */
              return -1;
        }  
        else if(this.student_id > tmp.student_id)
        {
              /* текущее больше полученного */
              return 1;
        }
        /* текущее равно полученному */
        return 0; 
      }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      /* Создание массива объектов Student
       * [ 13, Иван, yandex.ru, 356 ]
             [ 22, Яков, rambler.ru, 412 ]
             [ 4, Федор, mail.ru, 214 ]
             [ 43, Сергей, google.ru, 323 ]
             [ 17, Владимир, androidforums.ru, 108 ]
             [ 124, Николай, developer.android.com, 219 ]
             [ 9, Леонид, gasgoo.com, 588 ]*/

      Student[] students = new Student[7];
      students[0] = new Student(13,"Иван","yandex.ru", 356);
      students[1] = new Student(22,"Яков","rambler.ru", 412);
      students[2] = new Student(4,"Федор","mail.ru", 214);
      students[3] = new Student(43,"Сергей","google.ru", 323);
      students[4] = new Student(17,"Владимир", "androidforums.ru", 108);
      students[5] = new Student(124,"Николай", "developer.android.com", 219);
      students[6] = new Student(9,"Леонид", "gasgoo.com", 588);

      /* Сортировка массива */
      Arrays.sort(students);

      /* Печать отсортированных значений */

      for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
      {
        System.out.println(students[i].student_id + " - " +
        students[i].name + " - " + students[i].url + " - "+ students[i].res);
      }
    }
    }
```

Вот что выдает при выполнении этого кода:

```
4 - Федор - mail.ru - 214
9 - Леонид - gasgoo.com - 588
13 - Иван - yandex.ru - 356
17 - Владимир - androidforums.ru - 108
22 - Яков - rambler.ru - 412
43 - Сергей - google.ru - 323
124 - Николай - developer.android.com - 219
```

Надо тоже самое на андроид!

Comment: под андроид (если только не используете нативный код), оно должно заработать с пол пинка. Должно заработать сразу.

Comment: Не могу пинуть уже третий день. Это код примерный, у меня порядка 320 переменных. Но это не суть не получается на андроид хоть убей. Может подскажете как?

Comment: а чем проблема? ошибки? виснет? не умеешь копи-паст делать?

Comment: @vanyamelikov, с "примерным" кодом - это к телепатам. Если вот этот, приведённый в посте, работает, то нужно искать отличия от того, который не работает. Если же ЭТОТ не работает - разбираться с ним, а не с каким-то другим кодом.

Comment: Мой вопрос таков! Как этот же код реализовать на андроид. У меня выдает ошибку:
FATALEXCEPTION: main
Может действительно, все очень просто, но уменя ничего не выходит. Вы не могли бы перевести это джава код на андроид? Именно этот!

Comment: Он работает ка java application, переношу на андроид, естественно с исправлениями, то что в main() заношу в onCreate() и не работает!

Comment: Выношу в ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю как вам удалось заставить этот код не работать :) Вот код и скриншот с реального устройства (не эмулятора).

P.S. Прошу сильно не пинать - код не доводил до ума, это первая в моей жизни программа для андроида, написана на коленке за 3 минуты путём копипастной модификации "Hello, World!".

```
package org.example.hello;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
final class Student implements Comparable
{
  public int student_id;
  public String name;
  public String url;
  public int res;

  public Student(int student_id, String name, String url, int res)
  {
    this.student_id = student_id;
    this.name = name;
    this.url = url; 
    this.res = res;
  }

  /* Перегрузка метода compareTo */

  public int compareTo(Object obj)
  {
    Student tmp = (Student)obj;
    if(this.student_id < tmp.student_id)
    {
          /* текущее меньше полученного */
          return -1;
    }  
    else if(this.student_id > tmp.student_id)
    {
          /* текущее больше полученного */
          return 1;
    }
    /* текущее равно полученному */
    return 0; 
  }
}

public class Hello extends Activity {
    private TextView output;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

        Student[] students = new Student[7];
        students[0] = new Student(13,"Иван","yandex.ru", 356);
        students[1] = new Student(22,"Яков","rambler.ru", 412);
        students[2] = new Student(4,"Федор","mail.ru", 214);
        students[3] = new Student(43,"Сергей","google.ru", 323);
        students[4] = new Student(17,"Владимир", "androidforums.ru", 108);
        students[5] = new Student(124,"Николай", "developer.android.com", 219);
        students[6] = new Student(9,"Леонид", "gasgoo.com", 588);
        Arrays.sort(students);
        for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
        {
            output.append
            (
                    students[i].student_id + " - " +
                              students[i].name + " - " + students[i].url + " - "+ students[i].res + "\n"
            );
        }        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сейчас попробую, я делал то же самое только не final class, a просто class. И зачем @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") ?

Comment: Вы что, вручную код пишете, в блокноте? В Eclipse, например, каждый чих подробно разжёвывается, если мышкой на "красное" навести.

Comment: Все понял чтобы не ставить Comparable<Object>
Еще раз огромное спасибо! Просто final.